# Ionic google + login doesnt work, how to fix?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic google plus plugin for a login but it is not working. Here is the code I use :

```
  googleLogin(){
    this.googlePlus.login({
    })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

I installed :

```
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "8.1.2",
"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.0.0",
```

Ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.11.0 (C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.4, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 6 other plugins)
```

Error when I click :

> BuyerLoginPage.html:141 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at GooglePlus.login

Comment: Am I asked somehow wrong to get that - ?

Comment: did you add googlePlus in your `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: Added it to my Providers

Comment: Did you import it into your `page.component.ts`?

Comment: Yes I did, imported it : private googlePlus: GooglePlus

Comment: https://www.djamware.com/post/59094a2280aca7414e78a63d/ionic-3-google-plus-authentication-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Google login allows searching data and logging in your own api or firebase etc...

What is important is googleWebClientId, in my example i have created environment with googleWebClientId.

For example

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  googleWebClientId: "456149878-usaddsgfsdg784g5s6d4g8s7g.apps.googleusercontent.com"
};
```

The google webClientID isn´t real, just to show you how it´s looks.

And there is example of my google loggin in ionic with googlePlus.

```
   async doGoogleLogin() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: "Please wait..."
    });
    this.presentLoading(loading);
    this.googlePlus
      .login({
        scopes: "",
        webClientId: environment.googleWebClientId,
        offline: true
      })
      .then(
        user => {
          // save user data on the native storage
          this.nativeStorage
            .setItem("google_user", {
              id: user.userId,
              first_name: user.givenName,
              last_name: user.familyName,
              email: user.email
            })
            .then(
              () => {
               //method to login via api with data from google
                this.doLogin();
              },
              error => {
                this.snackBarService.openSnackBar(error, 1000);
              }
            );
          loading.dismiss();
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          if (!this.platform.is("cordova")) {
            this.presentAlert().then(() => this.router.navigate(['']));
          }
          loading.dismiss();
        }
      );
  }
```

And if you have problem with import do you have same import like this

```
import { GooglePlus } from "@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx";
```

You need to have this import in page.component.ts and app.module.ts

In app.module.ts you should have

```
   providers: [
    GooglePlus,
]
```